# RegEXP matching for web url in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find and match from video links like this :

http://www.aparat.com/v/HTFeu

So the last part which is HTFeu is needed and with bellow code I am verify the video link but I have problem with regExp statement.

```
var vurl = jQuery("#y_link").val();
var regExp = /^.*((aparat.com\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
var match = vurl.match(regExp);
if (match && match[7].length == 6) {}
else {
    alert("video link is not valid");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I checked the expression on regexr.com, there is no issue in the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a great tool like Rubular to try your regex: http://rubular.com/

This is meant for regex in Ruby but hey are almost the same than in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex for the end part to get

```
var regex =  \/v\/\w*; 
if(regex.indexOf("/") > -1){
    alert(regex.split('/')[2])
}
```

or you can try without regex

```
var string = "http://www.aparat.com/v/HTFeu";
    if(string.indexOf("/") > -1){
        alert(string.split('/')[-1])
    }
```